# Subscribe to all observables sequentially, and then emit values as array once all have completed

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm looking to make several sequential requests to a server. I need each of the requests to start as the previous request completes and then, once all of them have completed, emit the values as an array.

I've tried using `zip` and `forkJoin`, but these subscribe to all the observables in parallel. `concat` is almost there, but it emits as each of the observables completes, whereas I need it to hold off emitting until all observables have completed and then emit all the values as an array.

Comment: i think zip should solve your problem. http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-zip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `toArray` operator is simplier

```
concat(
  of(1),
  of(4),
  of(7)
).pipe(toArray())
```